# C++ create an array of size of a vector and then copy vector into C style array

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

VC++ is giving an error on below code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a;
    a.push_back(10);
    a.push_back(20);
    a.push_back(30);
    int arr[a.size()];
    std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), arr);
    for(int index = 0 ; index < a.size(); index++)
    {
        std::cout << " The value is " << arr[index] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

It errors out at the integer array declaration stating that the value of variable '**a**' cannot be used as constant?

How can we resolve the issue where my objective is to transfer content of vector into a '**C**' style array?

Comment: If you simply need an `int *` pointer to pass to a function, you can use `a.data()`

Comment: @Programmer - Please refer the updated answer. Earlier there were some wrong information in answer.

Comment: I may be naive for asking, but honestly, why do that? `auto copy_a = a;` will get you the very same thing, without any hassle, headaches or having to worry about the need to manually `delete[]` anything.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

What compiler tells you, is that `a.size()` is not a `compile time` constant ?. Hence, you cannot declare array like this. You need to call `int *arr = new int[a.size()];` and then delete it later.

Comment: No, the OP most certainly doesn't need to burden themselves with manually managing array lifetimes. Copying a vector to another vector is a one liner, and correct by construction.

Answer (score 3):

This error is compiler dependent. C++ demands constants in array definitions. Some compilers offer an extension that help to use non-constants while declaring Array. I successfully compiled your code on Xcode 10 (GCC).

For your compiler you can simply add  `int *arrPtr = a.data();` to get c-style array pointer for given array.

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a;
    a.push_back(10);
    a.push_back(20);
    a.push_back(30);
    //int arr[a.size()];
    //std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), arr);
    //for(int index = 0 ; index < a.size(); index++)
    //{
    //    std::cout << " The value is " << arr[index] << std::endl;
    //}

    int *arrPtr = a.data();
    for(int index = 0 ; index < a.size(); index++)
        std::cout<< " The value is " << arrPtr[index] << std::endl;

    for(int index = 0 ; index < a.size(); index++)
    {
        std::cout<< " The value is " << *arrPtr << std::endl;
        arrPtr++;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Some compilers need constants while declaring Array"* - No, the C++ **language** demands constants in array definitions. Some compilers just offer an extension that is beyond C++.

Comment: @StoryTeller - thanks for explaining. Updated answer accordingly.